# Why does my Bootstrap Modal window doesn't work on php? When I try to open the modal window it won't display

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I created a table with too buttons: delete and another one to  "see
other profiles" (this button displays a modal, and the button loops
throughout the table. It should display the modal, but it doesn't for
some reason. I already corrected as many mistakes as I could,  yet the
button doesn't display the modal)

```
function crea_tabla_foros() {    
    /* here I create a query to select my tables*/
    /*I execute it */       
    $rs = ejecutar($q);
    /*I create a while to make the table dynamic */ 
    $contenido = " ";
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    /*calling mysql*/
        $id_foro = $r['id_foro'];
        $nombreforo = $r['nombreforo'];
        $usuario = $r['usuario'];
        $comentarios = $r['comentarios'];
        $id_comentarios = $r['id_comentarios'];  
        $contenido .= "
            <tr>
                <td style='color:black;'>$nombreforo</td>
                <td style='color:black;'>$usuario</td>
                <td style='color:black;'>$comentarios </td>
                <td>
                    <form method='post' action='bak_foros.php'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_comentarios' value='$id_comentarios'>
                        <input class='trash' type='submit' name='eliminar' value='Eliminar'>
                    </form>
                    /*HERE IS THE BUTTON FOR THE MODAL*/
                    <button data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver'>VER</button>**
                </td>
            </tr>"
```

Here is the modal that should display and it is located inside the
body but outside the PHP function:

```
<div id="ver" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">PERFILES DE PARTICIPANTES</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <p></p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="publicar">PUBLICAR</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

> Here is the link [click  here](http://www.dis.ibero.mx/grupos/2018p/int3/equipo01/bak_foros.php)

Comment: Please post your code! It's hard to help you when it's all in pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed you modal inside the following div

```
<div class="filterDiv pendientes">
```

Which has a css `display:none` property. Place it outside this div and it should show.

Comment: Glad to help you :)